# Using DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind when binding DateTime with IConfiguration

Tags: c#, datetime, asp.net-core

TL;DR: I would like the result of binding `DateTime` values from `IConfiguration` to be the same as `DateTime.Parse(stringValue, null, DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind)`, but by default it is the same as `DateTime.Parse(stringValue)`.

---

I'm using the binding functionality of `IConfiguration` to pull `DateTime` values out of configuration.

Say I have a JSON configuration that looks like this:

```
{
    testValue: "2020-03-08T14:37:46.9793888Z"
}
```

I might pull the value out as a `DateTime` in one of a few ways. Here are the first two I thought of:

```
// Directly from IConfiguration
var dateTimeValue = configuration.GetValue<DateTime>("testValue");
```

```
// By configuring options

// Assuming this class exists
private class TestOptions
{
    public DateTime TestValue { get; set; }
}

// Set up options on a service provider
var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.Configure<TestOptions>(configuration);
var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

// Get as a service
var options = provider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<TestOptions>>().Value;
return options.TestValue;
```

The result of doing these, at least by default, is more or less equivalent to applying an ordinary parse:

```
// Bad, ignores Kind
var dateTimeValue = DateTime.Parse(stringValue)
```

I'm working on code that pays attention to the `Kind` property of the `DateTime`. The ordinary parse ignores "Z" times and makes anything with a time zone indication `Local`. An invocation like this, with the `RoundtripKind` style, fixes the problem:

```
// Good, uses Kind if available
var dateTimeValue = DateTime.Parse(stringValue, null, DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind);
```

Is there any way to force the configuration binder to use this invocation instead of the default?

Answer (score 0):

I had a thought: I could replace the `DateTime` field in the option class with a wrapper type, then implement the parsing on that. We change the type of the field like so:

```
private class TestOptions
{
    //public DateTime TestValue { get; set; }
    public RoundtripDateTime TestValue { get; set; }
}
```

We make up a wrapper type (I made it a `struct`, but a `class` also works), including implicit conversions to and from `DateTime` (so that at least some code doesn't need to be changed) and nice `Parse()` and `ToString()` methods. We include a `[TypeConverter]` attribute so that the configuration binder detects the converter class.

```
    [TypeConverter(typeof(RoundtripDateTimeTypeConverter))]
    public struct RoundtripDateTime
    {
        public RoundtripDateTime(DateTime value)
        {
            Value = value;
        }

        public DateTime Value { get; set; }

        public static implicit operator DateTime(RoundtripDateTime roundTripDateTime) => roundTripDateTime.Value;
        public static implicit operator RoundtripDateTime(DateTime dateTime) => new RoundtripDateTime(dateTime);

        public override string ToString() => Value.ToString("o");
        public static RoundtripDateTime Parse(string s) => DateTime.Parse(s, null, DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind);
        public static RoundtripDateTime Parse(string s, CultureInfo culture) => DateTime.Parse(s, culture, DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind);
    }
```

Finally, we include a new `TypeConverter` implementation that will handle instances of the wrapper. (I cheated and looked up the source to `DateTimeConverter` to find out what it was already doing, but this is actually much simpler <s>because it always operates in culture-ignorant mode.</s> [Edit: For conversion from `string`, added culture to help `Parse()` deal with datetimes that aren't in the ISO8601 format. It's still pretty simple.])

```
    public class RoundtripDateTimeTypeConverter : TypeConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
        {
            return (sourceType == typeof(string)) || base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
        }

        public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
        {
            if (value is string stringValue)
            {
                var text = stringValue.Trim();

                if (text == string.Empty)
                {
                    return (RoundtripDateTime)DateTime.MinValue;
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        return RoundtripDateTime.Parse(text, culture ?? CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    }
                    catch (FormatException e)
                    {
                        throw new FormatException($"'{value}' is not a valid value for {nameof(RoundtripDateTime)}.", e);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
            }
        }

        public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
        {
            if (destinationType == typeof(string) && value is RoundtripDateTime roundtripDateTimeValue)
            {
                return (roundtripDateTimeValue.Value == DateTime.MinValue)
                    ? string.Empty
                    : roundtripDateTimeValue.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
            }
        }
    }
```

This all may require some tweaking, but I think I have something I can work with.

If you have any better ideas, feel free to add another answer.